# nvidia errors in dmesg on startup i2c_transfer failed

Tags: 18.04, nvidia

I'm on 18.04.3 and am looking at dmesg and there are errors at startup around my graphics card, does anyone understand this?

[image]

Card is a 2080Ti

The same log as text:

```
Jan 13 20:53:29 mercury kernel: [    5.151016] nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
Jan 13 20:53:29 mercury kernel: [    5.151021] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
Jan 13 20:53:29 mercury kernel: [    5.151021] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
Jan 13 20:53:29 mercury kernel: [    5.155944] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
Jan 13 20:53:29 mercury kernel: [    5.161686] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 511
Jan 13 20:53:29 mercury kernel: [    5.162042] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
Jan 13 20:53:29 mercury kernel: [    5.166776] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
Jan 13 20:53:29 mercury kernel: [    5.166791] NET: Registered protocol family 31
Jan 13 20:53:29 mercury kernel: [    5.166792] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
Jan 13 20:53:29 mercury kernel: [    5.166795] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
Jan 13 20:53:29 mercury kernel: [    5.166796] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
Jan 13 20:53:29 mercury kernel: [    5.166798] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
Jan 13 20:53:29 mercury kernel: [    5.202379] ucsi_ccg 1-0008: i2c_transfer failed -6
Jan 13 20:53:29 mercury kernel: [    5.213888] ucsi_ccg 1-0008: i2c_transfer failed -6
Jan 13 20:53:29 mercury kernel: [    5.214408] ucsi_ccg 1-0008: failed to reset PPM!
Jan 13 20:53:29 mercury kernel: [    5.214839] ucsi_ccg 1-0008: PPM init failed (-6)
Jan 13 20:53:29 mercury kernel: [    5.261573] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  440.33.01  Wed Nov 13 00:00:22 UTC 2019
```

Comment: It is OK. There is no problem with that.

Comment: @davidbaumann don't know why you removed the image, the image didn't hurt and it added information, that those entries were in RED, you cannot see that from the plain text.

Comment: @Pilot6 Can You explain why this message is not an issue ?